# Add a number prefix to a regular expression in r

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I have a list contains characters with different lengths, I want to add prefix for characters with specific length.

```
library(tidyverse)

a = list("20013536", "20017954","19618","18114")
a
```

[[1]]
[1] "20013536"

[[2]]
[1] "20017954"

[[3]]
[1] "19618"

[[4]]
[1] "18114"

I want to add the numerical prefix "200" to the third and fourth elements of the list.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mohamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste()` to add any prefix to a vector of characters. In your example, I would just append the prefix `"200"` to characers shorter than 8 digits:

```
a = list("20013536", "20017954","19618","18114")

a[nchar(a)<8]=paste("200",a[nchar(a)<8],sep="")
```

The output would be:

```
> a
[[1]]
[1] "20013536"

[[2]]
[1] "20017954"

[[3]]
[1] "20019618"

[[4]]
[1] "20018114"
```

No tidyverse is required.